# JS: Formatting ISO Date String to Custom Format?

Tags: javascript

I have an ISO Date string such as "2020-08-12T03:02:47Z".  I want to convert these to "August 12, 2020 3:02PM".  Would I have to concert it to a timestamp and work backwards to accomplish this?

Comment: Why PM? The time part of the ISO string has 03 as hour, so that would be AM.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the moment.js package

npm i moment

```
console.log(moment(yourVariable).format('LLLL'))
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatting options of the Internationalization API. For instance like this:

```js
let fmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { 
    dateStyle: "long", 
    timeStyle: "short", 
    timeZone: "UTC", 
    hour12: true 
});

// Demo
let str = fmt.format(new Date("2020-08-12T03:02:47Z"));
console.log(str); // "August 12, 2020 at 3:02 AM"

// Optional: when you don't like the "at" or the space before "AM" or "PM":
str = str.replace(/ (..)$| at\b/g, "$1");
console.log(str); // "August 12, 2020 3:02AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to build a new date and from this get the values and reformat them.
For month use an array. For the hours get AM/PM and the hours (0-12/0-11 = 0-23). For the 2-digit minutes add before a string "0" and get than the last 2 chars. For hours you could even so but you show us hours as 1-digit.

```js
const MONTH = ['January,', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'JUly', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

let date = new Date ('2020-08-12T03:02:47Z');
let time = date.getHours();
let hours = (time<13) ? time : time % 12;
let amPm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
date = MONTH[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ', ' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + amPm;
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to use `moment` suing format `'LLL'`. Like this:

```js
let date = '2020-08-12T03:02:47Z'

console.log(moment(date).format('LLL'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```